# UITableViewCell selected on edit mode

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

A UITableViewController is getting loaded with multiselection and **ON EDIT** mode.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

....

    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;

}
```

The result is this one:
[image]

However this is not what I am looking for, since I want after the viewWillAppear some cells to be already selected.

I would like to be like this

[image]

What code do I need on `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` ???

Do I need code in any other method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of selected ones, that could be `BOOL` variable in your model, `NSArray` of `indexPaths`, or anything in between.

So what you should do in you `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if( dataModel.shouldBeSelected == true){
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected"];
}
else{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"empty"];
}
```

note that you have to take care of the non-selected ones so you can prevent reuse of selected cells and showing incorrect results.